# play a looping css animation only while scrolling - stop when scrolling stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a css animation on a fixed div that plays continuously.  I would like to have it only play when the user is scrolling and stop when the scroll stops.  I'm new to this and can't figure it out for the life of me.

my css:

```
.flame {
margin:0 auto;
position:absolute;
width:100px; 
height:136px;
background:url('../images/flame.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
-webkit-animation: flicker .4s infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes flicker { /* flame pulses */
0% {
    background-position:0px 0px; 
    opacity:.8 
}
    25% {
        background-position:0px 0px;
}
    25.1% {
        background-position:-100px 0px;        
}
    50% {
        background-position:-100px 0px;
        opacity:.4
}
    50.1% {
        background-position:-200px 0px;
}
    75% {
        background-position:-200px 0px;

}
    75.1% {
        background-position:-100px 0px;
}
    100% {
        background-position:-100px 0px;
        opacity:.8
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="flamegroup">
       <div class="flame" id="fl1"></div>
       <div class="flame" id="fl2"></div>
       <div class="flame" id="fl3"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there is an `onscrollstart` (and `onscrollstop`) event. Just an `onscroll` event. You can make your own start/stop detection of course using `setTimeout`.

Comment: I looked it up, and found this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_scrollstart.asp  but how would you link that to this animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, every 100ms or so, you need to capture the scroll position, then wait a little bit and see if the scroll position has changed. If it hasn't, you can stop playing the animation. Example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var tempscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    setTimeout(function() {
    if (tempscroll == $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $(document.body).removeClass("scrolling");
    } else {
        $(document.body).addClass("scrolling");
    }
    }, 75);

}, 100);
```

And your css would apply the animation only if the body has a .scrolling class

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dpfLs1L/)

Comment: thanks! but it is not working in the demo, it should be rotation on scroll, correct?

Comment: The css isn't prefixed with -webkit- prefixes, so it will only work in firefox. You will need to prefix the keyframe and the animation property to get it to work in safari/chrome

Comment: @HarryRobinsob http://jsfiddle.net/8dpfLs1L/2/ should also work in safari and chrome